# Python append adding same data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the stock price and the market cap data from a Korean website.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
response = requests.get('http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_market_sum.nhn?sosok=0&page=1')
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', { 'class': 'type_2' })
data = []
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    tds = list(tr.find_all('td')) 

    for td in tds:
        if td.find('a'):
            company_name = td.find('a').text 
            price_now = tds[2].text
            market_cap = tds[5].text 
            data.append([company_name, price_now, market_cap])    

 
print(*data, sep = "\n")
```

And this is the result I get. (Sorry for the Korean characters)

> ['삼성전자', '43,650', '100']
>
> ['', '43,650', '100']
>
> ['SK하이닉스', '69,800', '5,000']
>
> ['', '69,800', '5,000']

The second and the fourth line in the outcome should not be there. I just want the first and the third line. Where do line two and four come from and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Please explain what's wrong about the output and how the output should look like.

Comment: Sorry timegeb, The second and the fourth line in the outcome should not be there. I just want the first and the third line.

Comment: @KLee I think I do understand your problem! You should check out my answer, it works!

Comment: @KLee you want `['삼성전자', '43,650', '100']` or `['삼성전자', '43,650', '2,802,035']` ?

Comment: @ewink, it was ['삼성전자', '43,650', '2,802,035']. Anyway, data was not the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My dear friend, I think the problem is you should check if td.find('a').text have values!

So I change your code to this and it works!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(
    'http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_market_sum.nhn?sosok=0&page=1')
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'type_2'})
data = []
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    tds = list(tr.find_all('td'))

    for td in tds:
        # where magic happends!
        if td.find('a') and td.find('a').text:
            company_name = td.find('a').text
            price_now = tds[2].text
            market_cap = tds[5].text
            data.append([company_name, price_now, market_cap])

print(*data, sep="\n")
```

Comment: @KLee You're welcome, my dear friend! And I hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

While I can't test it, it could be because there are two a tags on the page you're trying to scrape, while your for loop and if statement is set up to append information whenever it finds an a tag. The first one has the name of the company, but the second one has no text, thus the blank output (because you do `td.find('a').text`, it tries to get the text of the target a tag).

For reference, this is the a tag you want:

```
<a href="/item/main.nhn?code=005930" class="tltle">삼성전자</a>
```

This is what you're picking up the second time around:

```
<a href="/item/board.nhn?code=005930"><img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/imgstock/images5/ico_debatebl2.gif" width="15" height="13" alt="토론실"></a>
```

Perhaps you can change your if statement to make sure the `class` of the a tag is `title` or something to make sure that you only enter the if statement when you're looking at the a tag with the company name in it.

I'm at work so I can't really test anything, but let me know if you have any questions later!

Comment: I see what's going on here. It was that img that was creating all this mess.

Comment: Yup! Glad the other two answers were able to provide you code while hopefully my answer helped you realize what the root cause was. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

check `tds` it should be equal to 13 and no need multiple `for` loop

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_market_sum.nhn?sosok=0&page=1')
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', { 'class': 'type_2' })
data = []
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(tds) == 13:
        company_name = tds[1].text 
        price_now = tds[2].text
        market_cap = tds[6].text 
        data.append([company_name, price_now, market_cap])   

print(*data, sep = "\n")
```

result

```
['삼성전자', '43,650', '2,802,035']
['SK하이닉스', '69,800', '508,146']
['삼성전자우', '35,850', '323,951']
['셀트리온', '229,000', '287,295']
['LG화학', '345,500', '243,897']
```

Comment: This one works perfectly as well. Thank you so much.